# rspec how to reuse code in example groups

Tags: rspec

What I am trying to do is this:

```
describe Specs::Specs do
  shared_context 'common' do
    def get_property(type)
      subject.send(type)
    end
  end

  describe 'attributes not needing conversion' do
    include_context 'common'
    # USE THE CODE HERE
    get_property(:weight)
  end
end
```

I want to dry up setting examples but I keep getting errors like:

> `get_property` is not available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or `context` block). It is only available from within individual examples (e.g. `it` blocks) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. `before`, `let`, etc).

How do I make methods available in nested example group?
How do I make variables available in nested example group?

Answer (score 0):

When I have needed helper methods in rspec, I have created a separate module. I saved the module as /spec/support/helper_method.rb, then in spec_helper or rails_helper.rb, within the "RSpec.configure do |config|" block, I added "config.include HelperMethod".

[These docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/helper-methods/define-helper-methods-in-a-module) explain this configuration further.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can pass `'include_shared => true'` as the examples show: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-context#declare-a-shared-context-and-include-it-with-metadata